# Max flow, min cut on manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

If a graph has some half edges marked "input" and some half edges marked "output", it is well known that the smallest number of edges which must be cut to disconnect input from output is equal to the number of edge-disjoint paths from input to output.  In the Riemannian context, say on a closed $d$-manifold, I believe the generalization is that the infimum $(d-1)$-volume of an integral $(d-1)$-cycle ( say submanifold) in a fixed homology class is equal to the supremum of closed $(d-1)$-forms integrated on that class, subject to the constraint that the $L^\infty$ norm of the form is at most 1. This is an $L^1$-$L^\infty$ duality.

I do not know a reference for this and would like to. Does this generalize to all $p < d$ cycles and closed $p$-forms?

Comment: Thurston made some cryptic remarks along these lines at his 60th birthday conference, and in the same sentence referred to a preprint with Claire Mathieu, titled "Rotation distance between binary trees: hyperbolic geometry vs. max-flow min-cut".  Amazingly this is referred to exactly once online: http://theory.stanford.edu/~aflb/1992-93.html -- perhaps contacting Prof Mathieu is the right course of action.

Comment: Thank you Sam for your editing, and the thought that Claire Mathieu might know about this.  Mike

Comment: I think you're searching for the concept of a calibrated manifold. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibrated_geometry

Answer (score 3):

It's good to read a clearly-stated  geometric version of max-flow min-cut.  I remember reading that in the thesis of John Sullivan, [A Crystalline Approximation Theorem for Hypersurfaces](http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/Papers/thesis/).  A linear optimization textbook usually only states the case for graphs.

Since I am here, read the thesis, perhaps I should get on a soapbox and discuss it some when I can.

Comment: Thanks John for your suggestion.  Regarding a possible analog theorem for p<d-1, I would guess that the correct restriction on closed p-forms might be that point-wise their evaluation on *primitive* , unit volume, p-planes is at most 1. This weaker than that bound on all unit volume *formal* p-planes. For example unit area formal 2-planes in R^4 form the unit 5-sphere in the exterior square, R^6, but the primitive subset is a copy of S^2xS^2. Mike